# Can't get image URL from Parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am having a hard time trying to retrieve an image URL that I am saving and writing to parse like so:

```
 var fileUploadControl = document.getElementById('img1');
 var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
 var name = "icon.png";
 var iconImageFile = new Parse.File(name, file);
 iconImageFile.save().then(function() {
     var user = Parse.User.current();
     var url = iconImageFile.url();
     user.set('imagePicture', url);
     user.save();
});
```

This all works fine and dandy. And at this point I am able to retrieve this value by saying:

```
var myImage = Parse.User.current().get('imagePicture');
console.log(myImage) // returns 'http://files.parsetfss.com/../icon.png'
```

However, when I refresh the page and the user is still signed in, when I go to retrieve this image by the same method:

```
var myImage = Parse.User.current().get('imagePicture');
console.log(myImage) // returns null
```

It returns `null`. I am able to get any other user values such as email, username, color, etc, but it gets hung up on an image; which is just a string to my knowledge. It must be a very simple issue that I am overlooking. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The call to `save` is asynchronous, meaning that it will set `imagePicture` *sometime* in the future. You need to ensure that the function has been called before retiring `imagePicture`.

Comment: Thanks @Olenader! The image has saved. And I can see the value in Parse. It just seems to not retrieve this value when I refresh the page with a user already signed in. Since the user is already signed in, and the image has been saved from a previous session, it should be available no?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve for it. Looks like I needed to use the fetch method instead:

```
Parse.User.current().fetch().then(function (user) {
    console.log(user.get('imagePicture'));
});
```